# How to change size from specific geom in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot containing 2 layers `geom_point` and `geom_line` as shown below.

```
gp <- ggplot(data = mtcars , aes(x = disp , y = hp)) + 
       geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line(size = 1 , color = "red")
```

`

[image]

Once the plot created, inside the `gp`, I want to change the size of only one `geom` (e.g line). How can I do that ?

Comment: Hi, You could see in the question I already used it to set size. My problem is, I want to change once the plot created (in the object `gp`),

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wish to replace the existing size with a smaller one (or replace a solid linetype with a dashed one, a filled shape with an unfilled one, etc.), overlaying may not have the best visual effect. As an alternative, you can dig into the specific layer of the ggplot object you've created, & manually change the parameters there.

(Note that this requires you to know the order of geom layers in the object.)

```
gp$layers[[2]]$aes_params$size <- 0.5 # change the size of the geom_line layer from 1 to 0.5
gp$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- 1   # change the size of the geom_point layer from 3 to 1
```

[image: plot]

I assume your use case involves modifying a ggplot object outputted by some package's plotting function? Otherwise, it's probably simpler to specify the desired parameters at the point of plot creation...

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I was looking for. I am getting plot as an output of some function. Later, I want to change as per my need.

Answer (score 1):

You can override specific properties of the plot keeping rest of them as it is

```
library(ggplot2)
gp + geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Or with `geom_line`

```
gp + geom_line(size = 5, color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Cool!! Works fine. :)  Thanks

Comment: Hi, Though it's working ok there's one problem. adding new geom add another layer rather overriding existing one. Due to this, it just hide the property of previous layer.

Comment: @Chirag yes, this adds a new layer on top of the previous one.