# How to update parameters of a geom in ggplot2 after it has been created

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

How can I update aspects of a `ggplot2` `geom` object after it has been created? I'm using `sjPlot`'s `plot_models()` function to visualize the fixed effects of multiple mixed-effects models, and I'd like to increase the size of some text annotations that it creates with `geom_text()` as well as increase the size of errorbar lines that it creates with `geom_errorbar()`.

Here's an example:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(lme4)

data1 <- data.frame(y = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    ran_effect = rep(c(1:10), 10),
                    x1 = rnorm(100),
                    x2 = rnorm(100, 4, 10))

data2 <- data.frame(y = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    ran_effect = rep(c(1:10), 10),
                    x1 = rnorm(100),
                    x2 = rnorm(100, 4, 10))

m1 <- glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | ran_effect), data = data1,
            family = binomial())
m2 <- glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | ran_effect), data = data2,
            family = binomial())

my_plot <- plot_models(m1, m2, dot.size = 5, show.values = TRUE,
                       show.p = TRUE) +
    theme(line = element_line(size = 4))
```

I was expecting to see a `size` value that I could set when accessing the `geom` layers, as discussed in [Remove a layer from a ggplot2 chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13407236/2571049); however, there is no `size` value in either `str(my_plot$layers[[3]])` or `str(my_plot$layers[[4]])`, which correspond to the `geom_errorbar()` and `geom_text()` layers, respectively.

Is it possible to update this aspect of a `geom` after it has been created? I'd like to do this so that I can continue to use `sjPlot`'s `plot_models()` rather than having to create the plots myself.

Comment: Nevermind, after a little bit more searching, I found that this has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55450441/2571049

Comment: maybe this works out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940643/7199966